# indentation in PowerPoint 2013

Tags: vsto, powerpoint, indentation, powerpoint-2013

I would like to change text indentation in some PowerPoint object.

Paragraph -> Indentation -> before text

Paragraph -> Indentation -> Special -> Hanging (how to change it on FirstLine or None?)  -> By

From that what I've found in previous versions it could be done with

> paragraph.ParagraphFormat.FirstLineIndent = x;
>
> paragraph.ParagraphFormat.LeftIndent = x;

but now there is no such properties available.

Comment: In previous versions, you set indents on the shape's TextFrame, and the settings affected every paragraph in the textframe.  Now each paragraph has its own indent settings.

Comment: Where did you find it?  I couldn't find the indent properties. -- Please consider posting an answer to your question to help others with the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I figured it out.  Here's the trick: the `LeftIndent` and `FirstLineIndent` properties **only** exist on the `Microsoft.Office.Core.ParagraphFormat2` object.  They do **not** exist on the regular `Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.ParagraphFormat` object.

You can still change the format for an entire TextRange though (it doesn't have to be done at the paragraph level as the comments above specify).

The trick is to access your shape's `TextFrame2` property, instead of just `TextFrame`, this will ensure that the classes you get back are `TextRange2`, which will return a `ParagraphFormat2` instead of a regular `TextRange` and `ParagraphFormat`.

The following code worked for me:

```
myShape.TextFrame2.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.LeftIndent = (.13f * 72f); // .13 inches
```